# storing sessions inside database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

Read a lot of posts about storing sessions inside database but no one seems to provide proper information.Then i came across this post and i found it to be very helpful.

http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

Now what i don't understand with these posts is that they are taking a class named *Database* which contain certain functions in order to make *session* class work i.e. to store sessions inside database.

**Question :**  My question to you all is if it is possible please provide me with that database class even it means creating one  own database class file.Just to make sure all the functions that the session class is looking inside database class are found and working.

***Codepad***:http://codepad.org/mtvT3XXB

Comment: What do you mean by "provide me with that database class"? You want someone to just do your work for you or is there some subtlety to that phrase that I've missed?

Comment: i didn't mean it to be rude.That was just a request :3

Comment: Try it your self , if face to problem, then ask question

Comment: This isn't the right place for such a request I'm afraid - if you want help with code you've written, this is a very useful place to be. If you want someone to write your code for you, it tends not to be so useful

Comment: **The Database Class** can be found on a link on that tutorial page! Under the link [Roll your own PDO PHP Class](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/) _Are you sure you are up to Development_

Comment: why not just implement what is detailed in the article for which you posted the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article you cite has horrible issues with wording (example: "...we instantiate a copy of the database class...", which is just plain nonsense). But the basic thing behind such "database" class simply is to keep things generic for the reader, which makes sense.

To interact with a database you need some routines for things like connection handling, query execution and preparation and the like. These routines are typically implemented as methods of a class. Such a class is what the author refers to. He does not name a specific one since they are more or less exchangeable.

You don't actually have to implement your own class, you can use one of those already provided. A short overview is given in the php documentation (which you should read!):

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php

I suggest you pick the `mysqli` connector and go through a few tutorials to learn what it does and how to use it.